# Skip processing where values are blanks using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have an Excel sheet with email addresses, To, CC, Subject etc.

I have file paths to each attachment. These are statements. Some .PDF and some .XLSX depending on the request. Although I have the file path to each, some have multiple Columns E-L but not all rows will have a file path and not always a statement at the end of the path.

I need the VBA code to ignore blanks and missing files only attaching as found. This can be as many as 9 files or as little as one or none by row to recipient.

I cannot get it to run without error, in my Test environment, ignoring blank cells with no path or paths that do not have a file.

```
Sub SendMail()

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A196")

        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

        With objMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .CC = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            .Body = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
            .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
            .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
            .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
            .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 8).Value
            .Display
        End With

        Set objMail = Nothing
    Next cell

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is my first VBA project.

Comment: Your ask is beyond the scope of one question. Please narrow your focus to one issue so we can focus our attention and answer your question. Then do some research on your next problem, and come here if needed. Loop until project complete :)

Answer (score 0):

This will ignore your blanks cells in your range, assuming the values you want to ignore are in your Range A2 - A196.

Here, ignore really means to skip down to "Else" where your loop will start over. It is being ignored in the sense that the IF statement is telling it to do nothing when blank. The next line is "Next Cell" which will give you the desired result.

```
Sub SendMail()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A196")
If cell.value <> "" Then  'If NOT blank, do this (your code)
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With objMail
        .To = cell.Value
      .CC = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        .Body = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
        .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
        .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 8).Value
        .Display
    End With

    Set objMail = Nothing
Else 'If IS blank, do this (next cell)
End If 
Next cell

Set ws = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: the question was edited and now its unclear which blanks you want to ignore. Please clarify if the blanks down your range A2 - A196 needs to be ignored (if not I will delete this)

Comment: Thank you for your time/assist. Will try that in Test.  A2-A# current lines in.xlsx  Columns E-M have file paths to folders files saved monthly. Some as many as 9 attachments or as little as none dependent a .pdf or.xlsx that month.  Blank cells across Col. E-M down lines A2-A#. Recipients will have multiple attach by path in Col E-M and some only would have a path in column E. Some may not have a file that month so ignore ‘File not found’. Final, emails .display with all indicated attachments at end of indicated path and continue to run the macro down A2:A196 for all (recipients). ‘Else’ ty

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, and feel free to modify the code to suit your needs, of course..

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

```
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm